# jps process information unavailable - jconsole and jvisualvm not working

Tags: java, jconsole

After a windows update, my jps, jconsole et jvisualvm are not working anymore.

Jps gives me the process ids, but it tells me `process information unavailable`

And I'm unable to connect to those processes with jvisualvm as I used to.

I'm running the 1.6.0_22 jre.

I already had the problem in the past, tries [this trick](http://javaandco.wordpress.com/2009/11/17/jconsole-problem-process-not-visible-even-in-jps/), and it worked. But this time, bad luck, it does not help.

**Edit :** 
**I found a solution** : in my temp folder, I did destroy the `hsperfdata_<username>` folder. Apparently there was an issue with the case of my username. The folder was called hsperfdata_myname. After having been destroyed and re-created by a call to jps, it was called hasperfdata_MYNAME.

Very strange.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

In my temp folder, I did destroy the hsperfdata_ folder. Apparently there was an issue with the case of my username. The folder was called hsperfdata_myname. After having been destroyed and re-created by a call to jps, it was called hasperfdata_MYNAME.

Very strange.

Comment: Thank you, thank you, thank you , thank you... I was pulling my hair out

Answer (score 10):

On unix, make sure you are running as the user that started it.

Comment: Nice! Something like: sudo -u username jps

Comment: Nice one! I switched the user and all the information was available.

Answer (score 0):

we're having the same problem here.

The tmp folder trick didn't work for us, as well.

So far, we've found a few ways to make things work again:

- a system restore
- rename the temp folder under "C:\Documents and Settings\myusername\Local Settings" and create a new temp folder (I'm not sure that this is a safe thing to do, regarding to windows...)
- start removing stuff from temp folder manually
- probably the safest: run ccleaner, this will clean up the temp folder

Comment: I eventually found a solution (see the original question)

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a script to apply the work-around, which I call from some of my monitoring scripts, until this is fixed.

```
#!/bin/bash
# Name: fix_jps.bash
# Author: Cameron Pierce
#
# Purpose: create /tmp/hsperfdata directories that jps and jstat can work with

## VARIABLES
RETVAL=""
fileHSP=""
filePID=""
fileLOG=/tmp/fix_jps.log

# for every /tmp/hsperfdata_[name] directory that exists
for fileHSP in `ls -d /tmp/hsperfdata_*`; do
        #echo "entry ${fileHSP}" # DEBUG
        # if our search returns entries that are not directories, skip them
        if [ ! -d ${fileHSP} ]; then
                continue
        fi
        #ls ${fileHSP} # DEBUG

        # alternative to ls below
        #FINDFILES=(${fileHSP}/*)
        #if [ ${#FINDFILES[@]} -gt 0 ]; then
        #       echo "files in $fileHSP: ${#FINDFILES[@]} "
        #fi
    for filePID in `ls ${fileHSP}/ 2>> ${fileLOG} | grep "[[:digit:]]\{1,\}"`; do
            #echo "pid name: ${filePID}" # DEBUG
            # if the directory was empty, move on to the next fileENTRY
            if [ "${filePID}" == "" ]; then
                    #echo "the contents of the variable filePID appear to be empty \"${filePID}\"" # DEBUG
                    # remove the fileHSP if empty; this will clean up user hsperfdata dirs
                    rmdir ${fileHSP} 2>> ${fileLOG}
                    continue
            # if a symlink already exists, move on to the next fileENTRY
            elif [ -h /tmp/hsperfdata_${filePID} ]; then
                    #echo "symlink already exists for /tmp/hsperfdata_${filePID}" # DEBUG
                    continue
            fi
            #echo "name: ${filePID}"
            # if a process exists for filePID, create a symlink to the source file
            ps -eo pid | awk '{print $1}' | grep -q "^${filePID}$"
            RETVAL=$?
            # if a process exists with pid of filePID and a symlink doesn't exists, create symlink
            if [ $RETVAL -eq 0 -a ! -e /tmp/hsperfdata_${filePID} ]; then
                    ln -s ${fileHSP}/${filePID} /tmp/hsperfdata_$filePID
                    #echo ls -l /tmp/hs perfdata_${filePID} # DEBUG
            fi
    done
done

# remove broken symlinks
#find -L /tmp/hsperfdata_* -type l # DEBUG
find -L /tmp/hsperfdata_* -type l -delete
```