# Get main class of a running JVM using PID

Tags: java

Is there a way to to find the main class name of a running JVM using its PID?

This is something that is already done in jvisualvm, for example.

Answer (score 3):

The `jps` command can be used:

```
jps -l | grep pid
```

`-l` prints the full class name. See [this link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/share/jps.html) for the official documentation.

Comment: It worked for some of the processes but may still shows `-- process information unavailable`. Any idea why?

Comment: that is another question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5271907/jps-process-information-unavailable-jconsole-and-jvisualvm-not-working

Answer (score 1):

you can use below command

```
jps -m or jps -l
```

jps - `Java running processes`

it will list down all the ``processes and its `PID` running in OS